# Why is SFHFKeychainUtils failing with error errSecAuthFailed in a Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sfhfkeychainutils

The debug build of some code utilizing SFHFKeychainUtils that is working without complaint on the mac which I'm developing on is triggering an error on another mac:

The code makes use of the following methods provided by SFHFKeychainUtils:

```
+[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:accessGroup:error:]

+[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:accessGroup:updateExisting:updateExisting:error:]
```

A password is added for a username using `+[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:accessGroup:updateExisting:updateExisting:error:]`.  Some time later, an attempt is made to retrieve the password using `+[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:accessGroup:error:]`.  However, this method is returning the error; its domain is `SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain` and its code is `-25293` (so it is `errSecAuthFailed`).  This error is only returned when a password is in fact stored in the keychain (or at least when it is visible from Keychain Access).

Why is this taking place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a lack of code signing.  Code signing is required in order for the second machine to access the keychain.  The fix was to enable code signing for the debug build.